# CC3200 LaunchXL with ubuntu and VSCODE

Tags: ubuntu, ftdi, texas-instruments, openocd, d2xx

and thanks to correct me wherever I'm wrong, as I'm not expert at all!

I have read many post and threads but none work for my case.
I want to be able to edit, make, flash (and hopefully debug)
using VSCODE, a CC3200-LaunchXL, under Linux Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (64-bits), kernel 5.4.0-48-generic.

In my understanding, OpenOCD will open the FTDI chip on the LaunchXL board and in a "transparent way"
will load the executable file to the CC3200 chip. To do this it just needs the CC3200.cfg and the executable file.

I have downloaded the CC3200 sdk
CC3200SDK-1.5.0-windows-installer.exe
and installed it with wine64.
Went into ../cc3200-master/example/blinky/gcc, did a make clean and make, and did
openocd -f ../cc3200-master/tools/gcc_scripts/cc3200.cfg -c "program ../path_to/blinky.bin verify reset exit"

I have the following
"
Error: The specified debug interface was not found (ft2232)
The following debug interfaces are available:
1: parport
2: dummy
3: ftdi
...
...
"

I read that the FTDI ft2232 has 2 drivers,
one for the Serial Port (VCP), this one is built-in Ubuntu, and loaded when the FTDI chip is plugged in
one for data D2XX, https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/libftd2xx-x86_64-1.4.8.gz
I have copied the libusb into /usr/local/lib with
sudo cp release/build/lib* /usr/local/lib
made a SYMLINK with
sudo ln -s libftd2xx.so.1.4.8 libftd2xx.so
made it executable
sudo chmod a+rwx libftd2xx.so.1.4.8

Then, 2 things I need to do,
To give me permission to access the FTDI once plugged, by writing a udev rule and adding me to the dialout group and restart the session
This rule was taken from the web, I added a trigger.sh that just print the date in a tmp file for double checking the event has occured, which did.
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0451", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c32a", SYMLINK+="fhss", GROUP="dialout", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/trigger.sh", MODE="0777", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe ftdi-sio", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo 0451 c32a > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id'"
I thought the VCP driver had to be unloaded (rmmod ftdi_sio rmmod usbserial, loaded when plugged in) before calling the modprobe?
I am not sure what 0451 c32a > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id does, any help?

So when I try the EEPROM read example from
release/examples/EEPROM/read (clean and make) and I have
Library version = 0x10408
Opening port 0
FT_Open(0) failed

If I unplug the board, and repeat the same command... same output. so clearly the command doesn't even reach the USB port?
Anyway, this is where I am... thanks for your help

Also to note, when I plug the LaunchXL, dmesg shows "Ignoring serial port reserved for JTAG", not sure if that is normal.

Comment: update; Solved the Opening port 0 FT_Open(0) failed issue, I had to call and set my idVendor and idProduct  FT_SetVIDPID(0x0451, 0xc32a); before calling FT_Open()
I can see now all the detail of the chip. 
So is openOCD fails at the same missing FT_SetVIDPID call again? if so, how can I hook the 2 together?

Answer (score 0):

I am coding for the cc3200 under Debian Buster with VSCode. I am using the LaunchXL as SWD Debugger, so this will be similar to you.
Why are you using wine? There is a Linux sdk available. I have written a bootloader for a device using the cc3200, so you may use that as a starting point.

https://github.com/toniebox-reverse-engineering/hackiebox_cfw_ng

To Flash the binaries to your launchpad you could use this tool https://github.com/toniebox-reverse-engineering/cc3200tool